# Recursively find values for each key-value pair with matching keys

Tags: python

I have an example dictionaty for `rules, quantifiers, and transformations`, essentially, inside each `key` there belongs another key containing `ids` equal to `id`. I am trying to find all those that match and return  these id's that match as a dictionary in this format:

```
dictionary = {'rules':[...], 'quantifiers':[...], 'transformations':[...]}
```

Here is the sample:

```
test_dict = {
    'rules': [{'id': 123,'logic': '{"$or":[{"$and":[{"baseOperator":null,"operator":"does_not_contain_ignore_case","operand1":"metrics.123","operand2":"metrics.456"}]}]}',},
    {'id': 589,
    'logic': '{"$or":[{"$and":[{"baseOperator":null,"operator":"does_not_contain_ignore_case","operand1":"metrics.123","operand2":0}, {"baseOperator":null,"operator":"does_not_contain_ignore_case","operand1":"metrics.456","operand2":0}]}]}',},
    {'id': 51,
    'logic': '{"$or":[{"$and":[{"baseOperator":null,"operator":"does_not_contain_ignore_case","operand1":"metrics.789","operand2":"metrics.1"}]}]}',},],
    'quant': [{'id':123,
            'transIds': [1, 2, 3],
            'qualifiedId': 'metrics.123'},
        {'id':456,
        'transIds': [1, 6],
        'qualifiedId': 'metrics.456'},
        {'id':789,
        'transIds': [9],
        'qualifiedId': 'metrics.789'}],
    'trans': [{'id':1,
            'rules': [123, 120]},
            {'id':6,
            'rules':[589, 2]}]
}
```

Here was my attempt, however, I realised that the list `trans, rules` would be specific to each index ID, therefore, because `rules` is first in the `test_dict`, then the loop won't capture it because all values side by it are empty.

Essentially, I wanted to enter `logic` and capture all values `metric` that belong to the `ids` in `quantifiers`

Capture all `ids` from `quantifiers` that match the values inside `attr`

```
attr = [123, 456]
keys = list(test_dict.keys())
trans = []
rules = []
for iter in range(len(keys)):
    for in_iter in range(len(test_dict[keys[iter]])):
        
        if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('id') in attr:
            if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('transIds') is not None:
                for J in test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('transIds'):
                    trans.append(J)
        
        if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('id') in trans:
            if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('rules') is not None:
                for K in test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('rules'):
                    rules.append(K)

        if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('id') in rules:
            if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('logic') is not None:
                print(test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('logic'))
```

Comment: Can you please give a small test with known input and output to help us understand the task more precisely?

Comment: @Caridorc little tricky but essentially if `id` in `attr` for `quantifiers`, then get all `transIds`, then check these to `trans`, and go into trans and get all `ids` in `rules`, then check this against `rules`, then in rules go into `logic` and get all `metrics` ids belonging to `quantifiers`, and repeat until you have all matching ones.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it again, but this is the kind of thing where an example speaks a thousand words, so if you post an example with full input and output you will help answerers a lot to help you.

Comment: @Caridorc Oh well ... If I could do that then I would have figured it out! Turns out I did figure it but, but by separating them into parts. I couldn't figure out how to capture everything into a single loop. That would be a challenge!

Comment: I am happy that you figured it out :). I meant a really small hand made example, obviously to make a large example you would have needed the code already working.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out thanks to the comments; Instead of running it all inside a single loop, then I split the loops into parts which solved the `list` issue. However, the lines of code is far too long for this attempt:

```
attr = [123, 456]
keys = list(test_dict.keys())
trans = []
rules = []
qualified = []
quant_id = set()
import json
for iter in range(len(keys)):
    for in_iter in range(len(test_dict[keys[iter]])):
        
        if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('id') in attr:
            qualified.append(test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('qualifiedId'))
            if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('transIds') is not None:
                for J in test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('transIds'):
                    trans.append(J)
trans2 = set()   
for iter in range(len(keys)):
    for in_iter in range(len(test_dict[keys[iter]])):
        if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('id') in trans:
            trans2.add(test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('id'))
            if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('rules') is not None:
                for K in test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('rules'):
                    rules.append(K)
rules2 = set()
for iter in range(len(keys)):
    for in_iter in range(len(test_dict[keys[iter]])):
        if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('id') in rules:
            rules2.add(test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('id'))
            if test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('logic') is not None:
                logic = json.loads(test_dict[keys[iter]][in_iter].get('logic'))
                ks_or = list(logic.keys())
                for or_ in range(len(logic)):
                    for unl_or_ in range(len(logic[ks_or[or_]])):
                        and_logic = logic[ks_or[or_]][unl_or_]
                        ks_and = list(logic[ks_or[or_]][unl_or_].keys())
                        for and_ in range(len(and_logic)):
                            for unl_and_ in range(len(and_logic[ks_and[and_]])):
                                if and_logic[ks_and[and_]][unl_and_].get('operand1') in qualified:
                                    quant_id.add(and_logic[ks_and[and_]][unl_and_].get('operand1').split('.')[-1])
                                elif and_logic[ks_and[and_]][unl_and_].get('operand2') in qualified:
                                    quant_id.add(and_logic[ks_and[and_]][unl_and_].get('operand2').split('.')[-1])
                                else:
                                    continue
dictionary = {'rules':rules2, 'transformations': trans2, 'quantifiers': quant_id}
print(dictionary)
```

Result:

```
{'rules': {123, 589}, 'transformations': {1, 6}, 'quantifiers': {'456', '123'}}
```

Updated with `set` instead of list so only unique values remain.